# outlook signature template not changing vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook, signature, gpo

i have a vbscript that take word document template and change some word to another base on the user details. for some reason few users the changing process not success and they get the template as-is to her outlook signature. my script run as a login script by GPO
this is my code:

```
On Error Resume Next
'==================================================
'Create Outlook signature from Word template
'==================================================

'search text and replace function 
Sub SearchAndRep(searchTerm, replaceTerm, objWord)
    objWord.Selection.GoTo 1
    With objWord.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Text = searchTerm
        .Execute ,,,,,,,,,replaceTerm
    End With
End Sub
'----- Declarations -----
Const wdWord = 2
Const wdParagraph = 4
Const wdExtend = 1
Const wdCollapseEnd = 0

'--------------------------------------------------------------
'----- Modify these variables appropriately ----
'--------------------------------------------------------------
strTemplatePath = "\\DOMAINNAME\SYSVOL\scripts\"
strTemplateName = "SignTemplate.docx"

'----- Connect to AD and get user info -----'
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
strName = objUser.FullName
strTitle = objUser.Title
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMobile = objUser.Mobile
strCompany = objUser.Company

strEmail = objUser.mail
strWeb = objuser.wWWHomePage

'----- Apply any modifications to Active Directory fields -----


'----- Open Word template in read-only mode {..Open(filename,conversion,readonly)} -----
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = FALSE
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strTemplatePath & strTemplateName,,False)
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

'----- Replace template text placeholders with user specific info -----

SearchAndRep "[Name]", strName, objWord
SearchAndRep "[Title]", strTitle, objWord
if strCompany = ("blabla LTD") then 
SearchAndRep "[Company]", strCompany, objWord
Else 

SearchAndRepDel objWord
End if
SearchAndRep "[Phone]", strPhone, objWord
SearchAndRep "[Mobile]", ("M: " & strMobile), objWord
SearchAndRep "[email]", strEmail, objWord

'----- Replace template hyperlink placeholders with user specific info -----
'SearchAndRepHyperlink "[email]", strWeb, objDoc
'SearchAndRepHyperlink "[web]", strWeb, objDoc


'----- Set signature in Outlook -----
Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()
objSignatureEntries.Add "Default", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Default"

'see note below if a different reply signature is desired
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Default"


'----- Close signature template document -----
objDoc.Saved = TRUE
objDoc.Close
objWord.Quit

'-----close outlook-----
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
objOutlook.Quit


'----- Subrouting to search and replace template hyperlink placeholders -----
'         Note this can be picky...if it does not work re-create hyperlink in the template
'Sub SearchAndRepHyperlink(searchLink, replaceLink, WordDoc)
'   Set colHyperlinks = WordDoc.Hyperlinks
'   For Each objHyperlink in colHyperlinks
'       If objHyperlink.Address = searchLink Then                                
'           objHyperlink.Address = replaceLink
'           End If
'   Next
'End Sub
'---sub for solar----
Sub SearchAndRepDel(objWord)
    objWord.Selection.GoTo 1
    With objWord.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Text = "[Company]"
        Do While .Execute
            objWord.selection.Bookmarks("\Line").Range.Delete
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it work fine with office 2010 and 2007. i have this problem only with office 2013

Answer (score 0):

make sure the all users have read write access to template file SignTemplate.docx

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for the OP, but the answer lies in the source code comments:

```vb
'----- Open Word template in read-only mode {..Open(filename,conversion,readonly)} -----
[...]
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strTemplatePath & strTemplateName,,False)
```

The readonly parameter should be TRUE, not FALSE:

```vb
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strTemplatePath & strTemplateName,,TRUE)
```